# PayPal Express Checkout SOAP - Version error

Tags: php, xml, soap, paypal, wsdl

As usual, neither the support nor PayPal's various sites are really helpful here. The error I get is a plain "Version error", and its according error number "10006" also yields the exact same error, without any further information about where I got wrong.

I am using the version provided by the WSDL found at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl.

The SOAP message I'm producing currently is:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"
    xmlns:ns2="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">

    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:RequesterCredentials>
            <ns1:Credentials>
                <ns1:Username>[FILTERED]</ns1:Username>
                <ns1:Password>[FILTERED]</ns1:Password>
                <ns1:Signature>[FILTERED]</ns1:Signature>
            </ns1:Credentials>
        </ns2:RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns2:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
            <ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
                <ns1:Version>121.0</ns1:Version>
                <ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
                    <!-- Transaction details here -->
                </ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails>
            </ns1:SetExpressCheckoutRequest>
        </ns2:SetExpressCheckoutReq>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried putting the `Version` tag into various places and changed namespaces, just to be sure, but everything gives me the same error, if not "method not supported".

According to the docs at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/PayPalSOAPAPIArchitecture/ and as far as I am understanding them, the XML should be correct...

Anyone here with a helpful idea or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've come across similar issues in the past with XML and it almost always comes down to namespacing.  I know you said you tried that already, but I would look into that again.

You can use the demo on this site, which will give you functional SOAP request samples, to compare and see what you might have wrong.

Another option, since I see you're using PHP, would be to grab this [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It includes functional samples for all of the API calls as well as empty templates.  All you have to do for any API is open up the sample/template, fill in the array parameters with your own data values, and it handles the rest.  You could have Express Checkout done in just a few minutes, and you wouldn't have to pull your hair out over getting XML formatted correctly.